# How to check if a string character is in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a JavaScript function that tells how many times a vowel was repeated in a given string.

Here's what I have tried:

```
    function checkVowel(str) {
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    str = "hello world"
    
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(str[i].includes(vowels)){
            console.log("worked")
        } else {
            console.log("not worked")
        }
    }
}
checkVowel()
```

How can I make this function check for each vowel rather than the entire array at once?

Comment: `str[i].includes(vowels)` => `vowels.includes(str[i])`. You might also want to remove the hardcoded `str = "hello world"`--call the function with `checkVowel("hello world")` instead, so you can reuse the function for different strings.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of occurrences for each vowel, or how many vowels there are in total in that string?

Comment: The first one actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it this what you're looking for?

```js
function checkVowel(str) {
  const counts = Object.seal({ a: 0, e: 0, i: 0, o: 0, u: 0 });
  
  for (let char of str) {
    counts[char.toLowerCase()]++;
  }
  
  return counts;
}

console.log(checkVowel("hello world"));
```

Comment: Perfect combination of `seal` and `for of` loop. Learned something new.

Comment: But it fails if any charater is in upper case

Comment: Now, I have been trying to display the number of times a vowel was repeated using string template literal but it's not working. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @IshaanSharma Same game. Make a new question *(don't mix multiple/different questions in one post)*, show what you've tried, what you got and what you expected. Even with my answer and your comment above, there's a dozen ways that you could have written this and a hundred things that could have gone wrong.

Comment: Got it! Thought duplicates post aren't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution**

```js
function countVowel(word) {
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  const wordArray = word.split("").map((s) => s.toLowerCase());
  const result = {
    a: 0,
    e: 0,
    i: 0,
    o: 0,
    u: 0
  };
  return wordArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (vowels.includes(curr)) {
      ++acc[curr];
    }
    return acc;
  }, result);
}

console.log(countVowel("Angel"));
```

Comment: What's your intention? Downwards compatibility? And since you already have it: `curr in result` is quicker O(1) than `vowels.includes(curr)` O(n)